# Understanding geometry of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I'm watching a lecture on multivariate calculus, and in drawing the vector $\langle 3, 2, 1 \rangle$, the professor encloses it in a box. I cannot figure out how, in a natural way, to construct a box given a single vector. My understanding is that any two independent vectors span a plane and any three independent vectors span a parallelepiped. Is there a way to construct such a drawing using only a single vector? Or is the only option to use the unit vectors along the coordinate axes in conjunction with it?

Comment: The professor is likely using the box to demonstrate the roles of $3$, $2$, and $1$ in the vector's notation. These numbers are intrinsically connected to the standard basis. You could use coordinates in another basis to construct a parallelepiped around the vector (a box, if the basis is orthogonal). But no, there is no basis-free way to take one vector and build a box/parallelepiped around it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe he was referring to the components of $\langle 3,2,1\rangle$ on the direction of each coordinate axis.

In some sense, you can associate a box to each vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ in this way.

I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXi-SkzMY3g) video might be useful (5:42).

Comment: The video is very helpful. Thank you. Is the idea that this box is a parallelepiped spanned by the vectors $(3,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$ ,and $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @Math7503 Yes, in some sense you can think they "span" the parallelepiped. But be careful, because the word "span" has another sense in Linear Algebra.